# Remove duplicate column value

Tags: sql

Considering my table

```
+----+------+--------+----------+
| ID | Name | Salary | Month    |
+----+------+--------+----------+
|  1 | a    |   5000 | Jan      |
|  2 | b    |   5500 | Jan      |
|  3 | b    |   5300 | Feb      |
|  4 | b    |   5300 | Mar      |
|  5 | b    |   5300 | Apr      |
|  6 | b    |   5300 | May      |
|  7 | b    |   5300 | June     |
|  8 | b    |   5300 | July     |
+----+------+--------+----------+
```

I need to display

```
+----+------+--------+----------+
| ID | Name | Salary |  Month   |
+----+------+--------+----------+
|  1 | a    |   5000 | Jan      |
|  2 | b    |   5500 | Jan      |
|  3 |      |   5300 | Feb      |
|  4 |      |   5300 | Mar      |
|  5 |      |   5300 | Apr      |
|  6 |      |   5300 | May      |
|  7 |      |   5300 | June     |
|  8 |      |   5300 | July     |
+----+------+--------+----------+
```

Can any1 help

Comment: Which is your database? MS Sql server, Oracle, MySql etc.?

Comment: What is the logic that removes the name from rows 3-8?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the results are sorted by the `name` column (and probably then the salary?), you could use the analytic function `ROW_NUMBER` to single out the first one, and only print that one out.
You may want to tweak the query around a bit, but here's the main idea:

```
SELECT   id, CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN name ELSE null END, salary, month
FROM     (SELECT id, name, salary, month, 
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY salary) AS rn
         FROM   some_table)
ORDER BY name, rn
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query for MS Sql server:

```
select  
    a.ID, 
    case when a.Name=b.Name then NULL else a.Name end Name, 
    a.Salary, 
    a.[Month]
from YourTable a left join YourTable b 
  on a.ID=b.ID+1
```